# How to rebuild SVN directory structure from the working folder?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using TortoiseSVN 1.6.xx.

When I created SVN repository for the first time, I had various sub-folders in my working folder. I am the only user and I am using TortoiseSVN to act as a backup repository also. I don't check out files from the SVN repository as I am the only user of my working folder. I commit in the day end and start working on the same folder the next day.

Recently, I deleted few sub-folders from my working folder. Now, Tortoise is unable to commit my new changes. Sometimes it displayed a message to "Try Cleanup", and sometimes it displays message to first update my working copy.

I tried CleanUp, but nothing happened. I can't update my working folder with the last revision as I have made changes to the folder which were not commited.

How to get rid of this problem and rearrange the repository with the present working folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the working copy won't delete the local changes you made. Do it without fear. If you're really afraid of losing something, make a copy of you working copy to another folder, but it shouldn't be necessary.

BTW, if you worked with others and someone did a commit that is in conflict with one of your local changes, you would have to do an update and merge the changes before trying to commit again. It's a normal and usual thing to update a WC containing local changes.

Answer (score 1):

The message that your state is not the current one, so you have to do a cleanup or update, is normally the result of a change on the server (by others or by yourself using the repository browser). Just do that, and after that commit then your changes which should go then through.

Another possibility could be:

- Do the change on the server (removing directories)
- Update your local copy then

If you fear to loose something, do a local `export` from the menu of the directory you want to keep. This will only store your files, not the meta data of Subversion. And if everything is locally, and you don't have too much contents, a fresh checkout does not cost much ...